# One of the Ethernet ports is marked as Disabled, why?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have two computers with the same motherboard, which has two Ethernet ports.

On one computer, it works like a charm, no problems.

On the other computer, somehow, one of the port gets disabled by Linux (I verified the BIOS and it's ENABLED there) and also the speed of the other port is limited to 100Mbps instead of the expected 1Gbps, although that could be my cable causing a problem.

There is a sample of ifconfig. On the computer with the problem, the p5p1 is missing.

```
$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1292 (1.2 KB)  TX bytes:1292 (1.2 KB)

p4p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: xx::xx:xx:xx:xx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:315437 (315.4 KB)  TX bytes:32060 (32.0 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f7200000-f7220000 

[following missing on computer with problem]
p5p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 Memory:df100000-df120000
```

So I checked with `lshw` to see the network info and the `p5p1` is found, but somehow it gets DISABLED. If I connect my cable on that port, the port wakes up as expected (i.e. I see the lights turn on) but it's still missing under Linux.

```
$ sudo lshw -c NET
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: p4p1
       version: 00
       serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=2.1-2 ip=10.0.0.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:f7200000-f721ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:f7220000-f7223fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: p5p1
       version: 00
       serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=2.1-2 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7100000-f711ffff ioport:c000(size=32) memory:f7120000-f7123fff
```

Any idea why Linux would disable a port on boot?

---

Update:

I found out that I could enable the Ethernet port with:

```
sudo ip link set up p5p1
```

That doesn't really explain why it was down, though. And it's back to Disabled after a reboot.

(See [Enabling and disabling Ethernet in ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739499/enabling-and-disabling-ethernet-in-ubuntu-15-10))

---

As suggested by Chai T. Rex, I connected the long cable on another computer with a 1Gbps connection and it works just fine. I see that the connection is at 1Gbps and not 100Mbps...

Comment: What happens when you boot the bad computer connected to the good computer’s cables (don’t unhook the other ends of those cables, the only thing that should change is that the near ends of the cables are connected to the bad computer)?

Comment: Right now, they both are connected to the same 1Gb switch, one has a very long cable, though, and that's probably a CAT5. Are you asking whether it would work if I were to connect both computers directly to each others? Both cables direct between both computers? One is too short without moving the computers...

Comment: No. Disconnect the cables from the good computer and plug them into the bad computer. Don’t disconnect them from the switch.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Ah, got it! To see whether the cable is bad or the NIC. Good idea. I tested the cable with my laptop which supports 1Gbps and the NIC says 1Gbps... so I guess that computer NIC is damaged?

Comment: To be sure, the bad computer’s NIC should be checked directly. It might notice a problem that the laptop’s NIC doesn’t.