# Ubuntu 20.04 fails to detect ethernet after update

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am very new to Ubuntu and Linux systems so I don't really know much but my work computer is Linux. I've tried many different posts in the forum to solve this but could not solve the issue.

So after un update on 20.04, Ubuntu fails to detect the ethernet.
Network Manager is not appearing at the upper right corner when I click the settings appearing at the top-down menu: It only has VPN (stating Not set up) part showing.

I am not sure which info would help so I can add any upon request but here are some of the outputs..

Here's some of my outputs..

`ifconfig -a`

```
eno1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 6c:0b:84:aa:33:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xe7300000-e7320000  

eth0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 6c:0b:84:aa:33:ab  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xe7100000-e717ffff  

gpd0: flags=4240<POINTOPOINT,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2905  bytes 211673 (211.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2905  bytes 211673 (211.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: 6c:0b:84:aa:33:aa
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:32 memory:e7300000-e731ffff memory:e7339000-e7339fff ioport:7020(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 6c:0b:84:aa:33:ab
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=3.25, 0x800005d0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 memory:e7100000-e717ffff ioport:5000(size=32) memory:e7180000-e7183fff
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Also, this file doesn't exist...

```
cat: /etc/netplan/01-globally-managed-devices.conf: No such file or directory
```

Any insight would be helpful... Please let me know if any more info is needed!

**Edit**:
As requested, I am attaching the output, but basically the file does not exist...

`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
cat: '/etc/netplan/*.yaml': No such file or directory
```

I have to note though that after multiple reboots and failed attempts... I gave up at one point, and when I returned to work computer a day later, the ethernet connection was detected again after first reboot of that day.

This is the second time I've experienced this though, so I definitely do want to know if there is a permanent solution to this...
(other than crossing my fingers every time I do an Ubuntu update, praying that this doesn't happen.... :( )

**Edit2**:
This wasn't a permanent solution, but it seems like applying series of these commands work after putting the file as advised in `/etc/netplan/`.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo service NetworkManager restart
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
reboot
```

The problem is that I have to apply this every single time after a reboot, but at least I think I have a way of getting my Internet back. Not sure how to make this default though

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I have added the output, but basically it seems like there exists nothing inside the ```/etc/netplan``` ? Also added some updates on the situation... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Add the following:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Netplan is very specific about spacing, indentation, etc., so proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit the text editor (Ctrl+x).

Reboot. Is there any improvement?

Comment: After the reboot, it lost ethernet connection again. All the outputs of the command are still the same. I copied and pasted your codeblock while I had ethernet before reboot in the yaml file so I don't think spacing should be an issue

Comment: Do these commands produce any errors or warnings? `sudo netplan generate` followed by: `sudo netplan apply`

Comment: Both of the comments dont produce errors or warnings... but also no outputs

Comment: Doing these two commands after ```sudo ifconfig eth0 up``` & ```sudo service NetworkManager restart```, and then followed by ```reboot``` puts my ethernet back on. Not sure what would be the permanent solution but thanks I think I'm at the moment happy with this. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the ethernet is disabled. It is indeed picking up you have an ethernet adapter. For some reason has disabled it.

Check this answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/739502/1192064

*Quoted*

> Terminal Method (advanced, but works for all flavors)
>
> 1. Open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T.
> 2. In the terminal, type sudo ip link set down eth0.
> 3. Enter your password when prompted and hit Enter (NOTE: you will not see anything being entered. This is a security feature, and your
>    password is indeed being entered.)
> 4. Now, enable the Ethernet adapter by running sudo ip link set up eth0.